# follow redirection with python selenium phantomjs script

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs

i am working on python selenium `phantomjs` script where i need to click on a button(Content Store) and then result in opening a new window on browser i want my script to follow the redirection and jump to newly opened window ..i have already tried with `find_element_by_tag_name` , find `elemnt_by_id` and `find_element_xpath`..but nothing is working

here is the body of that button

```
<a href="/performAction?view=contentStore" id="contentStoreLiId" title="Content Store" class="TabImg" style="" onclick="return linkOnclick(this)">Content Store</a>
```

here is my sample code which i am working on

```
from selenium import webdriver
from  selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) " +"AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36")
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)

dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = user_agent
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap,service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get('https://abc/performAction?view=userLogin')
driver.save_screenshot('/ab/login.png')
driver.find_elements_by_id('userName')[0].send_keys('abc123')
driver.save_screenshot('/ab/username.png')
driver.find_elements_by_id('password')[0].send_keys('abc')
driver.save_screenshot('/ab/userpwd.png')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('submitbtn').click()
driver.save_screenshot('/ab/Home.png')
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="contentStoreLiId"]')
print link
link.click()
driver.save_screenshot(/ab/CS0.png')
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Clarify what you mean `not working` and add exception log if you got any

Comment: HI i don't gives any error ... but its does nothing .. just stays on the same page.. where i want to jump on to the new newly opened windows ...and start doing actions over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If clicking the button open a new tab, then you will have to switch the driver context to it. Otherwise driver will still be on first page, although new tab opened. After clicking you can switch the context like this:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="contentStoreLiId"]')
print link
link.click()
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

`driver.window_handles` returns the list of contexts(tabs) available, new opened tab will be in last index hence picking last context using negative indexing.

Comment: Hey @dejavu_cmd_delt.. thanks for the reply after following your suggestions ..its working now ... thanks a lot..

Comment: If it worked then please do accept the answer, so others know that question was answered.